# Finding maximum value for numeric secondary index in Riak

Tags: indexing, max, riak

Given a numeric secondary index in Riak I can do range queries, like:

> "Find me all values* with index "sn" between 1 and 10".

Is there a way to find the **maximum value** for a numeric index? I.e.

> "Find me a maximum value of index "sn".

* It actually finds all primary keys (not the values themselves), but here it does not matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't ask Riak to give you the maximum value for the 2i. You will have to execute a map/reduce job and parse each 2i value which includes a reduce job to find the maximum.

If this is an important part of your application there are other ways you can get around the problem. Once you find the maximum you can add a secondary index to the value which indicates that it's the maximum. If the maximum value changes over time you could:

- Map/reduce over the bucket where the 2i for `maxval_int` is `1`.
- If there's only one result, return it.
- If there are multiple results, reduce to find the max.
- Remove the `maxval_int` index from each object that is no longer the maximum.
- When adding new values check against the current maximum value, update indexes accordingly.

The little *read-repair*-like function is there to handle cases where nodes in your cluster are partitioned.

HTH.

Comment: It is wise to use mapreduce in production environment in Riak. Wouldn't it drop performance greatly?

Answer (score 0):

Or if your maxval is increased monotonically you can store it under special key like max_2i_index=25
Then if you set the bucket to allow siblings you could resolve potential siblings by providing simple mutator and conflict resolver. You may also consider setting up R, W, PR, PW, N appropriately to avoid inconsistencies.